# Eloquent morphTo issue in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `Project` model. Each `Project` can have a thumbnail, main image and other multiple assets / images (project details for example) and also multiple text contents (that would be placed in between these images). And each `Project` page will pull in these assets (except the thumbnail) and texts, and display them in a specific order (that I define by drag and drop on my control panel).

So basically the similar structure to what `Behance` uses for example. I'm trying to structure this using Eloquent and here is what I have so far:

I have models `Image` `Text` and `Node`. `Node` model's table has `order` column to custom order these nodes.

My polymorphic relationships look like these:

My`Project` model:

```
public function nodes()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany(Node::class, 'nodeable');
}
```

My `Node` model:

```
public function nodeable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Then in my code I do the following:

```
$project = new App\Project;
$project->title = 'Some title';
$project->save();

$image = new App\Image;
$image->source = 'somefile.jpg';

$project->nodes()->save($image);
```

But I get the following error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'project_id' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `nodeables` (`nodeable_id`, `nodeable_type`, `project_id`) values (5, App\Node, 1))'
```

So I guess it's trying to create an entry inside a pivot table `nodeables`. Then I created this table and it saved an entry inside the pivot table, but not inside `nodes` table.

This is driving me mad! :(

Answer (score 0):

Node is not been saved because your using the relationship to save an **image** model.There is no instance of a new Node object.

You need to define the relationships for Images and Texts in the Node model hence when it comes to saving you would use

```
$node = new App\Node;
$node->save($image);

$project->nodes()->save($node);
```

This will ideally save a node record in the database. However if the work of node is to only hold the order. Consider adding the field in the pivot table.

Comment: Thanks. I played around with it and finally got it to work, but instead of `$node->save($image)`, I had to use `$image->node()->save($node);`